# Cypress: Using cy.intercept() to check if a call hasnt been made yet?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

Using cy.intercept() to intercept (and stub) a couple of network requests (to google tag manager), but would like to test at an early point in my test before I expect them to be called.

How would I test that the 2 routes I'm intercepting **haven't** been called yet?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the pattern, are going to wait for a period, or visit and test immediately?

Comment: @AloysiusParker - It can be immediate. The pattern is we're dynamically generating DOM elements for a web-component with JS (ie. <my-component />), then setting an attribute (ie. <my-component title="this is my component" /> - when the attr gets set, we ping an API - so would like to test before setting the attr (no API ping) and then after setting the attr that the API was pinged... pung?... yeah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intercept has a routeHandler section which can be a function

> cy.intercept(routeMatcher, **routeHandler**?)
>
> routeHandler (string | object | **Function** | StaticResponse)

The function receives the request, and inside that another function can receive the response,
see [Intercepting a response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepting-a-response)

```js
cy.intercept('/integrations', (req) => {
  // req.continue() with a callback will send the request to the destination server
  req.continue((res) => {
    // 'res' represents the real destination response
    // you can manipulate 'res' before it's sent to the browser
  })
})
```

so either on the receipt of `req` or the inner function on receipt of `res`, set an external flag and test it at one or more places in the test,

```js
// top of the test

let interceptFlag = false;

cy.intercept('/my-route', (req) => {
  interceptFlag = true;
  req.continue((res) => {
    // or here
    interceptFlag = true;
  })
})

// later in the test

cy.wrap(interceptFlag).should('eq', false);   // not yet intercepted

// something triggers the API call

cy.wrap(interceptFlag).should('eq', true);    // now is intercepted
```

This is very generalized, if you post some details can be more specific.

Answer (score 15):

You could take advantage of the `cy.spy` command:

```
cy.intercept('/my-route', cy.spy().as('myRequest'));

// later in the test

cy.get('@myRequest').should('not.have.been.called'); // not yet intercepted

// something triggers the API call

cy.get('@myRequest').should('have.been.calledOnce'); // now is intercepted
```

See: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/spy
Credits to: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#check-if-the-network-call-has-not-been-made

Comment: Is there a way to use cy.spy and fixtures at the same time?