# How to test that a request has not been called with route2 in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to test a cookie consent banner with Cypress and route2. I have to use route2 because I have to test several types of network requests.

In my first scenario I want to make sure that, after accepting the consent, a request to Google Analytics is called.

Example:

```
cy.route2('https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js').as("getGA")
cy.visit("/")
cy.contains("button", "Accept", { timeout: 15000 }).click()
cy.wait('@getGA').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

In my second scenario I want to test that **no** request to Google Analytics is called before accepting the cookie consent.

I only found examples with cy.route() (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354360/is-there-a-way-to-assert-that-a-route-has-not-been-called-in-cypress) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295287/cypress-io-assert-no-xhr-requests-to-url)) but none with route2. Is this possible with route2?

Comment: May be cy.wait('@getGA').wait(4000).should('not.exist')

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately this did not work: "Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: getGA. No request ever occurred."

Comment: For the purpose of counting slow API response, I`ve been told by my seniors to put globalVariables: "defaultCommandTimeout": 60000,
    "requestTimeout": 60000,
    "responseTimeout": 60000,